# Resizing window in proportion

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can resize the window only in proportion?
It means even if you resize window vertically, also horizontal will resize in proportion.

I know a 'aspectRation' does for a div but I need it for window.
Please see example
http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/aspect-ratio.html

I would like to resize window this way
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mate,
This is how I made it work

```
imgRow = 8;
imgCol = 6;

max_w = $(window).width()/imgRow
max_w = $(window).width()/imgCol

if(max_w > 147) max_w = 147;//Not to exceed its original width
if(max_h > 147) max_h = 147;//Not to exceed its original height

$("img").each(function(i) {
    var this_w=$(this).height();
    var this_h=$(this).width();
    if (this_w/this_h < max_w/max_h) {
    var h = max_h;
    var w = Math.ceil(max_h/this_h * this_w);
    } else {
    var w = max_w;
    var h = Math.ceil(max_w/this_w * this_h);
    }
    $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to listen for the onsize event and do the calculations yourself (based on the previous size vs new size). you could then maintain the desired aspect ratio.